# Using a WCF hosted xml serialized object, how do change the order of the xml nodes when using XmlSerializer on the object

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

If I have an object like so:

```
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public class Person
{
   [XmlElement("LastName")]
   public string Last {get;set;}

   [XmlElement("FirstName")]
   public string First {get;set;}

   [XmlElement("Banners")]
   public List<Banner> Banners {get;set;}
}

[XmlType("Banner")]
public class Banner
{
    [XmlElement("Title")]
    public string Title {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("Location")]
    public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

When serializing it locally, it turns out to look ok

```
<Person>
   <LastName/>
   <FirstName/>
   <Banners>
       <Banner>
          <Title/>
          <Location/>
       </Banner>
    </Banners>
 </Person>
```

But if create a library and host it from a WCF IIS service, and I want to use it from a client application, when I access the Person object, fill it with my parameters and then serialize it to an xml string I get this:

```
<Person>
   <Banners>
       <Banner>
          <Location/>
          <Title/>
       </Banner>
    </Banners>
   <FirstName/>
   <LastName/>
</Person>
```

all the nodes are shown in alphabetical, per level after the root.  I have tried using the Order keyword in the XmlElement Attribute, but it doesn't see it apparantly.

Now if I use the object locally and serialize it, then it adheres to the Order keyword.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is XmlSerializer mandatory?

WCF is using the DataContractSerializer by default.

So I would switch to that.

The attribute is `DataMember` - instead of `XmlElement`.

With DataMember you can add an order value, that will be honored by the DataContract Serializer.

```
[DataMember(Order = 0)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
[DataMember(Order = 1)]
public string LastName { get; set; }
[DataMember(Order = 2)]
public string Email { get; set; }
[DataMember(Order = 3)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried to convert it to DataContract/DataMember Max, which the Order works if I am using the objects locally, but when I am accessing the objects that are within a service, filling them from the client and using DataContractSerializer on them.. they are still alphabetical.  It is almost as if it isn't even looking at the attributes when serializing.